# CSS animation/transform going off screen

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I'm animating text to each corner of the screen. In every corner the text is rotated. The problem here is that in the top right and bottom left corner the text goes off screen. I'm thinking it has somethig to do with the rotation.

My question is how can I keep the full text on screen with the correct position?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aeno3d30/)

```
#lorem {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    animation: switch 10s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes switch {
    0% {
        bottom:auto;
        top:3%;
        left: 3%;
        right: auto;
        animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
    }
    25% {
        left:auto;
        right:3%;
        bottom: auto;
        top: 3%;
        animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    50% {
        top:auto;
        bottom:3%;
        right: 3%;
        left: auto;
        animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    75% {
        right:auto;
        left:3%;
        top: auto;
        bottom: 3%;
        animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
}

<span id="lorem">Lorem</span>
```

Comment: It has a different behaviour in FF and in Chrome, is little hard to understand what you need

Comment: You'd have to change the `transform-origin` point I suspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your transform for 25% to

```
transform: rotate(90deg) translate(50px,0px);
```

and 75% to

```
transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(50px,0px);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aeno3d30/3/)

Comment: Note that the behaviour in Chrome is different from FF as noted the the comments to the original question.

Comment: The behaviour in chrome is the correct one, I forget to add prefixes for my transformations

Comment: @li0n_za this is what I needed but do you also know how I can maintain the same distance from the border as the corners where I don't have the issue

Comment: @AC3 unfortunately I am not certain, I have tweaked the `%`'s a bit so it looks a little better, but to get it perfect you will most likely have to do it with jQuery